# javafx 2.0 css styling not work

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2

I have the following code:

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

GridPane root = new GridPane();
final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
Label logol = new Label("Test logo");
logol.setStyle("-fx-color: red;");
root.add(logol, 0, 0);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

all that i am trying to do is that the label logol will have red foreground color
but it insisting on staying black.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no CSS property "-fx-color". To change the foreground color use "[-fx-text-fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled): red" instead.

Comment: See the [JavaFX 2 CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for css property name info.